# Remapping a keyboard key only when using a specific input language

Tags: keyboard, macos

I currently have 2 input languages on my Mac: U.S., and Hebrew - PC.

The Hebrew - PC is almost the same as it should actually be, except the tilde key (<kbd>`</kbd>) should actually type a semicolon (<kbd>;</kbd>), but instead it creates a backslash (<kbd>\</kbd>). I already have a designated backslash key, and in order to type a semicolon I actually need to hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd> which is extremely cumbersome.

I'd like to reassign this key to work properly, but only when using the Hebrew layout - the English one needs to keep its use as the tilde which I use for window switching and terminal home dir.

What are my options? I currently have copies of BetterTouchTool and Karabiner, if that helps.

Comment: Another option is Ukelele, which provides a simple interface to make a custom layout like you want in a couple minutes I think.

Comment: Just tried it out, looks like it will be global though, not limited by input language

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  You make a custom hebrew pc keyboard layout and use it to type Hebrew.  When you type English, I assume you would use the independent US layout, which has not been modified.